# Sending key to the app on a remote machine

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Generally what i'm trying to do is to programmically login into a social network site. 
My program opens a window with a WebBrowser element on it, sends special keys to itself, logs in and stores login data into a database. All of this is running on a remote server on Windows 2008.

Everything is fine when an RDP connection is active and the RDP window is in foreground. But when I minimize the RDP window or close it the application on the remote server cannot gain focus, even if it's started over and over. So the keys sent to the window are lost and nothing happens.

So far as I get it, I can try the two approaches:

1) send keys to the app that doesn't have focus at all (I heard it's nearly impossible)

2) get the window focused even on a remote machine without RDP currently connected

3) (just came to mind) login a different way than sending keys

Comment: Struggling with close the RDP window and it stops working, what else would it do?

Comment: What do you mean "struggling"? The app is meant to work for weeks nonstop

Comment: Struggling as in why a gui app would keep displaying stuff when no one was "looking" at it. Why do you expect it to keep focus? If you run it locally and minimise it does it still work?